# magento 2 too many session file

Tags: magento2.3, session

I know it may be asked before that for Magento 1 and I remember that I had this problem and fixed it by below config in php.ini

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
```

after many times I am facing a similar issue. I change session config like above but it still creates many session files (about 20-30 file in each minute).
how I can fix it?

Comment: This can be an indication your site is either being scraped, being checked for weakness (admin url or known exploits) or spammed forms. Check your access logs.

Comment: I check apache log and we haven't a lot of requests